# Why is a CITE tag not observing the following properties?

Tags: html, css

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
max-width: 100px;
width: 100px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhellman1/qQdDq/

white-space is taking effect, but width is not? Why? Is it something to do with the CITE tag or perhaps Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cite` is an inline element, so you have to specify `display: block` or `display: inline-block` for it to be constrained to width.

Answer (score 1):

`<cite>` is [inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1), it doesn't have width. if you add `display:block` or `display:inline-block`, on the other hand...

Comment: Did you hit submit prematurely?

Comment: @BoltClock why? am i too concise?

Comment: Your second sentence looked unfinished so I was wondering, but never mind, I see you added an ellipsis.